# How to split egrep print result in to multiple columns and export to a CSV file

Tags: python, bash, shell, csv, unix

I am trying to find all hardcoded strings in my xcode project and export the results to a csv file. the below script that i used is giving me all the list of values along with filename as one string (i.e. /path/classA.m @"Value") and when i export same results to csv file obviously everything is copied in to one column.

```
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" \) -print0 | xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --only-matching "($KEYWORDS).*\$" > myFile.csv
```

But i am trying to export the results in to csv so that i want to see filename under column and hardocded values in other column.

I am newbie in to scripting world. Please help me to get over this

Comment: Add some sample output

Comment: /Users/VRK/Documents/iPhone/MyProj/MyProj/AppDelegate.m: @"abc"

Answer (score 1):

```
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" \) -print0 | xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --only-matching "($KEYWORDS).*\$" | sed 's/:/,/' > myFile.csv
```

Csv represents comma separated values

Search and replace first occurrence of : with , as file and value are separated by : in your case.

Comment: thanks for ur answer. I have pasted the sample o/p that i m getting with my script. /Users/VRK/Documents/iPhone/MyProj/MyProj/AppDelegate.m: @"abc". and getting same o/p after adding ur script.

Comment: adding additional sed command to convert op to , separated csv file didn't work?

Comment: Mahesh, the problem is when i m trying to export this output to csv , the entire result is copied as one cell. but i am looking to split this text in to two parts (i.e. two cells) where filename can copy to onecell and @"abc" to other cell

Comment: Updated the answer to replace : with ,

Comment: Could you please add more information on why this would help answering the question?